# Elasticsearch Mutually Exclusive results

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch query which has a condition which checks whether `issoldout = false` . And based on it I have few Sum and Count Aggregation fields.

However I would like to get aggregation values if `issoldout = false` fetch no results, then try with `issoldout = true`. Is there any way that I can get this done without a second search with `issoldout = true`.

Comment: Multi-search is the first thing that comes to mind: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html

Comment: Thank You let me check with Multi Search.. But I doubt if there a way I could run the second query only if the first query fetch no results. ?

Comment: No, both queries will run and it'll be up to you to implement logic to decide which set of results to use - if performance is your concern though, I wouldn't worry about it. Elasticsearch is fast.

Comment: Thank you will go ahead and implement this.  Yes performance was a concern. Because the query is quite complex, the condition issoldout is just one part of it here...

Comment: if your queries are slow then it might be q case for an offline denormalisation process that'll allow you to index something more efficiently queryable.

Comment: Thanks I am thinking abt that as well as the current structure has got quite a bit of Nested Elements which require complex queries.. Though so far the performance have been satisfactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could literally submit two queries using `_msearch` as noted, but you could also just run them in parallel within the same request:

You can do this with the `filter` aggregation in order to get it to dive down both with it. Similarly, you could just use a `terms` aggregation to do it, but you would then get it when it's `false` too.

```
{
  "query": {
    ... normal query ...
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_soldout": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "issoldout": true
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "stats_for_field": {
          "stats": {
            "field": "your_field"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the recommendation, however in my scenario it will not work out as I have other Aggregation, which should be working on the aggregation. It also require the IsSoldOut condition...